# How to give select query a name in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query:

```
select distinct encoder.encoder enc, src_ip, encoder.datacenter 
from logical_service, unnest(tags) enc, encoder, mpeg_out 
where enc like 'encoder:%' 
  and substring(enc,9) = encoder.encoder 
  and logical_service.lid=mpeg_out.lid 
  and encoder.datacenter=mpeg_out.datacenter 
order by encoder.encoder
```

I would like to give this query a name so that I can later use it. I was trying to do this, but this ultimately fails:

```
with encoder_alias as (
  select distinct encoder.encoder enc, src_ip, encoder.datacenter 
  from logical_service, unnest(tags) enc, encoder, mpeg_out 
  where enc like 'encoder:%' 
    and substring(enc,9) = encoder.encoder 
    and logical_service.lid=mpeg_out.lid 
    and encoder.datacenter=mpeg_out.datacenter 
    order by encoder.encoder
)
```

It does not give any output as to why this is not working. Any idea why I can't use the with as to give it the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) needs to be followed by a final SELECT statement:

```
with encoder_alias as (
  select distinct encoder.encoder enc, src_ip, encoder.datacenter 
  from logical_service
     cross join unnest(tags) enc
     join encoder on substring(enc,9) = encoder.encoder 
     join mpeg_out on logical_service.lid = mpeg_out.lid 
                  and encoder.datacenter = mpeg_out.datacenter 
  where enc like 'encoder:%' 
  order by encoder.encoder
)
select *             ---<<< here
from encoder_alias;
```

<sup>(note that I replaced your ancient, outdated and fragile implicit joins with "modern" (30 years old) explicit `JOIN` operators)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I don't think OP was asking how to make the CTE work, but showing a misunderstanding of what a CTE does. It does not provide a name for a query. The best I can describe being it defines a 'view' (existing only for the duration of the full statement) for use within a subsequent query.
But for "give this query a name so that I can later use it" I think what being asked for is actually a function. (Now I could be totally off the boat here! and if so, so be it). The following would actually "name" the query for later use:

```
create or replace function encoder_alias()
  returns table ( enc TEXT, src_ip TEXT,  mpeg_out TEXT)
  language sql 
as $$
    select distinct encoder.encoder enc, src_ip, encoder.datacenter 
      from logical_service, unnest(tags) enc, encoder, mpeg_out 
     where enc like 'encoder:%' 
       and substring(enc,9) = encoder.encoder 
       and logical_service.lid=mpeg_out.lid 
       and encoder.datacenter=mpeg_out.datacenter 
     order by encoder.encoder
$$;
```

If this is what you looking for you'll have to supple the actual column types (not posted so I just used TEXT). 
 
BTW. I have not tested nor compiled the function, so syntax errors are possible. Further, I used original query but agree with you should update to the modern syntax.